# alter authorization in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-diagrams, authorization

I will to made a database diagram in my SQL Server Management Studio. But I have this warning that said:

> Database diagram support objects cannot be installed because this database does not have a valid owner. To continue, first use the Files page of the Database Properties dialog box or the `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` statement to set the database owner to a valid login, then add the database diagram support objects.

[image]

Can you help me whit this error? How can I give myself (hein_) the promision to continue?

@JeffersonBElias suggested me to execute this code:

```
select suser_sname(owner_sid) as usersname from sys.databases where name = 'FreeTimeDBSSA'
```

What me gives this:

```
+-----+-----------------------+
|     |       usersname       |
+-----+-----------------------+
|  1  | DESKTOP-3BMCMPC\hein_ |
+-----+-----------------------+
```

Here you have my Object Explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found it whit a hint from @JeffersonB.Elias. I've execute this code:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::FreeTimeDBSSA TO sa;
GO
```